# Where is `libX11.so.*` corresponding to LXDE?

Tags: xorg, java, lxde, matlab

I'm trying to link Matlab to the latest JRE, and I'm getting an [extremely slow GUI](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/234894) for which the solution seems to be to link Matlab to [an older X11 library](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-623399.html).

Since the problem is essentially caused by the new X11 libs being slow on the interface with Matlab through Java, I was thinking that perhaps a lighter implementation focused on performance such as in LXDE might do the job.

I installed the LXDE package without trouble, but now I'm looking for the corresponding `libX11.so.?`. Do you know where I might find that library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXDE still depends on X11 libraries, see the following dependency chain:

```
$ apt-cache depends -i lxde
lxde
  Depends: lxde-core
  [...]
$ apt-cache depends -i lxde-core
lxde-core
  Depends: lxde-common
  [...]
$ apt-cache depends -i lxde-common
lxde-common
  Depends: lxsession
$ apt-cache depends -i lxsession
lxsession
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0
  Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: lxsession-data
  Depends: lxsession-logout
  Depends: laptop-detect
```

Finally the `libX11.so.?` is provided by [libx11-6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libx11-6/filelist) at the following location (for a x86_64 system):

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
```